# Typing effect JS without the use of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typed.js

Hey guys I have got a JS code where I'm trying to animate, sort of like typing effect. I know I can use typed.js for this purpose but that requires passing in an HTML container. Which in this case, I don't have access, I mean that I have the index.html but this text I'm trying to animate isn't in HTML but in JS. Although for some reason when I inspect this text element on the webpage, it does show the text in HTML. I know it's kinda hard to understand so I've attached the code snippet for both index.html and JS code.

**JS CODE: HERE I WANNA ANIMATE THE subTitle part**

```
[![const greeting = {
  username: "Mr.",
  title: "Hi all,",
  subTitle: emoji(
    "A fanatic Full Stack Software Developer  having an experience of building Web and Mobile applications with JavaScript / Reactjs / Nodejs / React Native and some other cool libraries and frameworks."
  ),
  displayGreeting: true // Set false to hide this section, defaults to true
};][1]][1]
```

**index.html, you will notice that it doesn't contain the element I want to animate but it appears as part of it when I inspect the element on the webpage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png?v8=qAJ44G5Bm7">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-16x16.png?v8=qAJ44G5Bm7">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v8=qAJ44G5Bm7" color="#885bd5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico?v8=qAJ44G5Bm7">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#6c63ff" />
  <meta name="My Portfolio" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-touch-icon.png?v8=qAJ44G5Bm7">
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Portfolio" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://developerfolio.js.org/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://developerfolio.js.org/static/media/developerActivity.59389695.svg" />
  <link rel=preload href="/static/media/Montserrat-Regular.ee653992.ttf" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
  <link rel=preload href="/static/media/Agustina.21f233e1.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>

  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135618960-2"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-135618960-2');
  </script>
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome@5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

  <title>Trial/title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

[image: Image of the code from website]

Please help me solve this problem, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I stopped reading here: "_...text I'm trying to animate [is] JS_". You can't animate _text_, you will need a HTML element to animate.

Comment: But it's apparently there but I can't seem to animate it cuz I'm already passing on the input(string) from the JS file

Comment: The text you see is not in JS file, it's just dynamically inserted to the DOM, either to an exisiting element, or JS creates the element too.